# Joining two separate linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ query which results an array of Job records.
Due to LINQ-To-SQLs limitations/restrictions regarding cross-context queries, I can't do a join a table and so two of the fields for the Job record are empty.

I can however get these by doing a separate LINQ query.

My question is can I populate those two fields easily say for example by doing a join on those two queries? - and if so how?

```
query1.Join(query2,..... and so on);
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

```
var results = query1.Join(query2,
                        job => job.JobID,
                        other => other.JobID,
                        (job, other) => new
                        {
                            MissingField = other.Field,
                            OtherMissingField = other.OtherField
                        });
```

I am getting the error message:
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Func, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: JOINs work in L2S perfectly fine. Can you provide a simple version of the code that is not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is sized such that you can bring it all into memory, then you can do the join in LINQ-to-Objects; just add some `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` to the original queries - the LINQ to join them remains the same.

However; this cannot be used to join at the server. For that, either throw the tables you need into a single data-context, or cheat and use TSQL for that query. LINQ-to-SQL's `ExecuteQuery<T>` method is pretty handy for such purposes.

Comment: After much playing about I finally got there. It was a foolish mistake on my part by using anonymous types which it didn't like too much!